# Django Many to Many Data Duplication?

Tags: django, postgresql, database-design

**Background**

I'm storing data about researchers. eg, researcher profiles, metrics for each researcher, journals they published in, papers they have, etc.

**The Problem**

My current database design is this:
[image]

Each Researcher has many journals (they published in). The journals have information about it.
Likewise for Subject Areas

But currently, this leads to massive data duplication. Eg, the same journal can appear many times in the Journal table, just linked to a different researcher, etc.

Is there any better way to tackle this problem? Like right now, I have over 5000 rows in the journal column but only about 1000 journals.

Thank you!

EDIT: This is likely due to the way im saving the models for new data (mentioned below). Could anyone provide the proper way to loop and save hashes to models?

Model - Researcher

```
class Researcher(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    scopus_id = models.BigIntegerField(db_index=True) # Index to make searches quicker
    academic_rank = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    scopus_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    scopus_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    affiliation = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, null=True,max_length = 255)
    department = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, null=True,max_length = 255)
    email = models.EmailField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    properties = JSONField(default=dict)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}, Scopus ID {}".format(self.scopus_first_name,self.scopus_last_name,self.scopus_id)
```

Model - Journal

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    researchers =  models.ManyToManyField(Researcher)
    title = models.TextField()
    journal_type = models.CharField(max_length=40,default=None,blank=True, null=True)
    abbreviation = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    issn = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    journal_rank = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    properties = JSONField(default=dict)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

How I'm currently saving them:

```
db_model_fields = {'abbreviation': 'Front. Artif. Intell. Appl.',
 'issn': '09226389',
 'journal_type': 'k',
 'researchers': <Researcher:  x, Scopus ID f>,
 'title': 'Frontiers in Artificial Intelligence and Applications'}
# remove researchers or else create will fail (some id need to exist error)
researcher = db_model_fields["researchers"]
del db_model_fields["researchers"]
model_obj = Journal(**db_model_fields)
model_obj.save()
model_obj.researchers.add(researcher)
model_obj.save()
```

Comment: If you have a ManyToManyField in your model, a journal in Journal is unique, the row is unque in your database. Can you show your models.py file please?

Comment: You have a N:M relation between Researcher and Journal. Why your data is duplicate? How can we can help you to avoid is? Do you need help to identify similar Journals? Explain.

Comment: @Bestasttung Added :)

Comment: @danihp What I mean is, I have, say, 400 Journals, and 150 researchers. But when adding to the database this way, the same journal appears duplicated many times in the Journal table, just with different researchers. so I have 5000 journal rows, but only 400 unique ones

Comment: Then, just change User Interface to select a Journal instead off add new one if it already exists.

Comment: @danihp Not sure I understand, do you know how to do this in code?

Comment: adding a relation doesn't create a new journal if it already exist. What you say about journal duplicating in your Journal table is not possible if you've made a manytomany field. Read my answer. It's created in a third table, which make relation between the two models bound by the manytomany relation. So there's not a researcher attribute in your journal table.

Comment: @Bestasttung As I said, I have over 5000 journal rows, but much lesser actual unique journals. So clearly something is going wrong somewhere

Comment: @Wboy i've edited my anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it works :

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    # some fields

class Researcher(models.Model):
    # some fields
    journal = models.ManyToManyField(Journal)
```

Django gonna create a relation table :

> Behind the scenes, Django creates an intermediary join table to represent the many-to-many relationship

So you'll have many rows in this table, which is how it works, but `journal` instance and `researcher` instance in THEIR table will be unique.

Your error is maybe coming from how you save. Instead of :

```
model_obj = Journal(**db_model_fields)
model_obj.save()
```

Try to just do this:

```
model_obj = Journal.objects.get_or_create(journal_id)
```

This way you'll get it if it already exists. As none of your fields are unique, you're creating new journal but there's no problem cause django is generating unique ID each time you add a new journal.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but this is one of the first things I tried which failed. get_or_create returns a ValueError: “needs to have a value for field ”id“ before this many-to-many relationship can be used”.

Comment: well i don't know how you get those fields, but just get the journal id with it and call get_or_create on it.

Comment: How do you propose i do that? i have a hash which i want to create a Journal object from. If the journal already exists (and linked to some researcher), i want it to map to the new researcher now

Comment: Is there a view ? a form? what is your code when you look for a researcher and journal to bind them?

Comment: Literally what i have above. I have a list of hashes of attributes for the journal object, along with a 'researchers' key which has an actual researcher object.

Comment: well again can you just do a get_or_create on the fields and tell me what it returns.

Comment: Sokay I fixed it with alot of manual checking. Thanks man @Bestasttung